# How to enable keyboard accessibility of individual svg sub elements

Tags: html, svg, accessibility

I'm mostly inexperienced with accessibility and svg, and trying to update some existing code to improve accessibility features.

Have a list of links and a manually rendered bar chart sort of feature, and the request is to be able to tab through the bars.  For reasons not understood by me, the entire bar area is not reachable with by tabbing.  The list of links is.

I'm including some partial html below.. in this example I am able to tab to the part titled "Am able to tab to this" but unable to tab to the part titled "Want to be able to tab to this"

```
<svg class="svgWrapper" width="1300.159979248047" height="458.87999267578124" transform="translate(114.71999816894531, 0)">
   <g class="mainGroupWrapper" transform="translate(292.5359953308106, 68.83199890136719)">
      <g clip-path="url(#clip)" class="mainGroup" style="clip-path: url(&quot;#clip&quot;);">
         <rect y="0" width="715.0879885864259" height="74.12676804762619" class="bar" fill="#B5B5B5">
            <div title="Want to be able to tab to this" tabindex="1"></div>
         </rect>
         <rect y="123.54461341271032" width="204.31085388183595" height="74.12676804762619" class="bar" fill="#B5B5B5">
            <div title="Want to be able to tab to this as well" tabindex="1"></div>
         </rect>
          <rect y="247.08922682542064" width="51.07771347045899" height="74.12676804762619" class="bar" fill="#B5B5B5">
            <div title="Want to be able to tab to this as well" tabindex="1"></div>
         </rect>
         <g class="axis axis--y" transform="translate(0,0)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end">
            <path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M0.5,0.5V321.71599487304684"></path>
            <a xlink:title="Am able to tab to this" xlink:target="_blank" xlink:href="foo" text-anchor="start">
               <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,37.06338402381309)">
                  <line stroke="currentColor" x2="0"></line>
                  <text fill="#0000EE" x="-268.5359953308106" dy="0.32em" style="font-size: 12px;" font-family="&quot;Roboto&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif">Foo</text>
                  <foreignObject x="-292.5359953308106" y="-6" width="24" height="24" color="#0000EE"><i class="fas fa-file fa-lg"></i></foreignObject>
               </g>
            </a>
```

I had read that adding a title to an element within the rect would do it but it's not working for me.

Comment: 1. rect elements can't have children 2. all html content in SVG must be enclosed in a <foreignObject> parent element.

Comment: or are those div elements not real and you want to tab to the rect itself, in which case give the rect a tabindex attribute.

Comment: Seems to work if I add a tabIndex to the rect , with or without the foreignObject, but I can add that, I didn't realize it was required.
If you wan to answer the question I can mark it the answer.

Comment: There are a lot of accessibility concerns associated with this, what would a screen reader read out when they land on your SVG shapes? If I am a keyboard user do I really need tab stops on these bars (as I won't be able to see the `title` anyway), does it add a benefit or does it actually make the page harder to use? Only things that are interactive (and can be activated by a keyboard) should be accessible via the Tab key, given the example I would question whether you need this at all. Also think about adding a `<title>` element to your SVG (not a `title=""` attribute) etc.

Comment: I was having each bar read something along the lines of "XX% of people..." which is what the bars represent.  

This was my interpretation of what the issue was asking for, based on some input from an accessibility assessment, but I am a total beginner in this area so I have very little idea what is considered a best practice.